# How to write query that returns all values in Device_ID column if 5 or more of the same values in Event_Code column are listed for the same Device_ID

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to write a statement that returns all values in the Device_ID column if 5 or more of the same values in Event_Code column are listed for the same Device_ID

The query needs to return a result that is grouped by the Device_ID, and display the Event_Code and how many Event_Code instances were found per Device_ID.

For Example:

```
Device_ID     Event_Code
28105         70000
28105         70000
28105         70000
28105         70000
28105         70000
28105         70001
25115         70001
25115         70001
```

The query should return:

| Device_ID | Event_Code | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 28105 | 70000 | 5 |

Comment: This is a basic `GROUP BY` query.  Have you tried *anything*?

Comment: Please can u give us your try? It's easier to correct it

Comment: Hi,

What I need is an output to also include all Device_IDs that have 15 or > '70000' Event_Code per day, 15 or > '70001' Event_Code per day, 3 or > '70002' Event_Code per day, and 5 or > '70003' Event_Code per day.

Here is the code thus far:

SELECT
    history_log.device_id,
    history_log.time,
    history_log.event_code
FROM
    history_log
WHERE
    history_log.event_code in ('70001','70002','70003','70004')
    AND history_log.time >= '01-JUN-21'
    AND history_log.time < '01-JUL-21'
ORDER BY
    history_log.device_id,
    history_log.time DESC

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
SELECT device_id, event_code, COUNT(*)
FROM device_events
GROUP BY device_id, event_code
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5;
```

You want a `GROUP BY` to clump your results together for you.  You want it to be pairs of Device_id + event_code.

Then instead of a `WHERE` clause like a normal query, you'll want a `HAVING` clause.  This is like a WHERE, but specifically for aggregated values while a WHERE is for individual rows.  So `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5`

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE device_events (device_id int, event_code int);

INSERT INTO device_events (device_id, event_code) VALUES
(28105, 70000),
(28105, 70000),
(28105, 70000),
(28105, 70000),
(28105, 70000),
(28105, 70001),
(25115, 70001),
(25115, 70001);

SELECT device_id, event_code, COUNT(*)
FROM device_events
GROUP BY device_id, event_code
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
I guess I should have added that I originally had a WHERE clause that follows

WHERE event_code in ('70000','70001','70002,'70003')
AND time > '01-JUN-21'

how would I incorporate this into my query while using the HAVING clause?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You wouldn't need to change anything.  WHERE goes between FROM and GROUP BY, so you would just insert your lines in there.  ```SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY ... HAVING```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to apply these event_code filters and date filters and also want to consider a hit at (device_id, event_code) level as a hit at the device_id level and return all device_id, event_codes which exist in input data even if some combinations are less than 5. A hit (success) for specific event_code becomes a hit (success) for all event_codes for that device_id.

For complicated processing of this sort including additional requirements, its useful to try and apply SQL Pattern Matching (MATCH_RECOGNIZE keyword) a new capability in Oracle Database 12c onwards. This feature is now available in a few other DBs recently.

```
DROP TABLE device_events;
CREATE TABLE device_events (device_id int, event_code int);

truncate table device_events;
INSERT INTO device_events (device_id, event_code) VALUES (28105, 70000);
INSERT INTO device_events (device_id, event_code) VALUES (28105, 70000);
INSERT INTO device_events (device_id, event_code) VALUES (28105, 70000);
INSERT INTO device_events (device_id, event_code) VALUES (28105, 70000);
INSERT INTO device_events (device_id, event_code) VALUES (28105, 70001);
INSERT INTO device_events (device_id, event_code) VALUES (28105, 70003);
INSERT INTO device_events (device_id, event_code) VALUES (28105, 70003);
INSERT INTO device_events (device_id, event_code) VALUES (28105, 70003);
INSERT INTO device_events (device_id, event_code) VALUES (28105, 70003);
INSERT INTO device_events (device_id, event_code) VALUES (28105, 70003);
INSERT INTO device_events (device_id, event_code) VALUES (28105, 70003);
INSERT INTO device_events (device_id, event_code) VALUES (28105, 70003);
--Added 70004
INSERT INTO device_events (device_id, event_code) VALUES (28105, 70004);
INSERT INTO device_events (device_id, event_code) VALUES (28105, 70004);
INSERT INTO device_events (device_id, event_code) VALUES (28105, 70004);
INSERT INTO device_events (device_id, event_code) VALUES (28105, 70004);
INSERT INTO device_events (device_id, event_code) VALUES (28105, 70004);
INSERT INTO device_events (device_id, event_code) VALUES (28105, 70004);
INSERT INTO device_events (device_id, event_code) VALUES (25115, 70001);
INSERT INTO device_events (device_id, event_code) VALUES (25115, 70001);
commit;


SELECT device_id, event_code, COUNT(*)
FROM device_events
GROUP BY device_id, event_code
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5;



SELECT device_id, event_code, COUNT(*)
FROM device_events
WHERE 1=1
and event_code in (70000,70001,70002,70003) 
--AND time > to_date('01-JUN-2021', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
GROUP BY device_id, event_code
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
;


with QDE as (
select  device_id, event_code, count(1) as cnt
from device_events
where 1=1
and event_code in (70000,70001,70002,70003,70004) 
--AND time > to_date('01-JUN-2021', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
GROUP BY device_id, event_code
order by 1,3 desc,2
),
--select * from QDE;
QDE2 as (
select 
   --MRQ.* 
   --device_id,
   --event_code,
   --cnt,
   case when cl = 'EC5' then DEVICE_ID_EC5 else DEVICE_ID_OTH end as DEVICE_ID,
   case when cl = 'EC5' then EVENT_CODE_EC5 else EVENT_CODE_OTH end as EVENT_CODE,
   case when cl = 'EC5' then CNT_EC5 else CNT_OTH end as CNT,
   device_id_ok,
   nvl(max(device_id_ok) over (partition by device_id), 'N') as device_id_ok_wf
from QDE deev
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
   PARTITION BY device_id
   order by event_code
   MEASURES
      max(case when ec5.cnt >= 5 then 'Y' else 'N' end) as device_id_ok,
      ec5.device_id as device_id_ec5,
      ec5.event_code as event_code_ec5,
      ec5.cnt as cnt_ec5,
      oth.device_id as device_id_oth,
      oth.event_code as event_code_oth,
      oth.cnt as cnt_oth
      ,
      match_number() as mn,
      classifier() as cl
   ALL ROWS PER MATCH 
   --ONE ROW PER MATCH
   AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST LAST ROW
   PATTERN ((ec5|oth)*)
   DEFINE
           ec5 as (case when cnt >= 5 then 1 else 0 end = 1),
           oth as (case when cnt < 5 then 1 else 0 end = 1)
) MRQ
WHERE 1=1
order by 1,3 desc, 2
)
-- NOTE: 
-- device_id_ok is a flag which qualifies (device_id, event_code) combination
-- ... use to get all combinations which are greater than or equal to 5.
-- device_id_ok_wf is a flag which qualifies device_id across event_codes
-- ... use to get all combinations incl those which are less than 5. 
select *
from QDE2
where 1=1
and device_id_ok_wf = 'Y'
order by 1,2,3
;


 DEVICE_ID EVENT_CODE        CNT D D
---------- ---------- ---------- - -
     28105      70000          4   Y
     28105      70001          1   Y
     28105      70003          7 Y Y
     28105      70004          6 Y Y
```